# Make app iPad1 compatible

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

Good evening,

My app is a simple calculator that starts with a main menu. It is working as designed on my iPad2, but a friend who downloaded it in the App Store is unable to even launch to the main menu on his iPad1.

There seem to be no memory issues, according to Instruments.

I set the deployment target in the summary screen to iOS 5.0. Is there anything else I need to do to get this to work on iPad1?

Comment: Oh, and I am using storyboards, if that's relevant.

Comment: Hey George, No Nothing else is required. Does iPad 1 has iOS 5.0 and above? And are you using any feature in the app which is not in the iPad 1 (e.g camera)? Ask your friend to send you a crash report from his device. That will give you a better idea about the issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: Make sure to download the 'iOS 5.0 Simulator' and test with this. It is not installed by default in the later XCode versions.